# I need to rename Pentaho url from localhost:8080/pentaho/Home to localhost:8080/renamed_text/Home

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Hi Guys After we land from login page to Pentaho home page I need to change the URL and remove Pentaho from their example before:- `localhost:8080/pentaho/Home` to After `localhost:8080/some_text/Home` i.e change the pentaho route name..